# Equality of infimal integral over family of functions, with and without pointwise closure

Tags: measure-theory, pointwise-convergence

**Question:** Suppose that $(X, \mathcal{A})$ is a measurable space. Let $\pi$ be a probability measure which is supported on a finite subset of $X$.
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of functions $X \to (-\infty, +\infty]$.
Is it true that
$$
\inf_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \int f \, \mathrm{d} \pi = \inf_{f \in \bar{\mathcal{F}}} \int f \, \mathrm{d} \pi?  
$$
Above, $\bar{\mathcal{F}}$denotes the pointwise closure of functions $f \in \mathcal{F}$ within the space of functions $X \to [-\infty, +\infty]$.

---

I can see this is true if the following two conditions hold:

- If $f \in \bar{\mathcal{F}}$, then $f > -\infty$; and
- Let $S$ denotes the support of $\pi$, then $2^S \subset \mathcal{A}$.

Suppose these conditions hold. It is then enough to show that for any $f \in \bar{\mathcal{F}}$ that
$$
\sum_{x \in S} f(x) \, \pi(\{x\})  \geq \inf_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \sum_{x \in S} f(x) \, \pi(\{x\}).
$$
For this, let $f_n \to f$ pointwise with $f_n \in \mathcal{F}$. We may assume that $f$ restricted to $S$ is finite (meaning never $+\infty$) otherwise the inequality is immediate. Now note that since this is a finite sum, we clearly have
$$
\sum_{x \in S} f(x) \pi(\{x\}) = \lim_n \sum_{x \in S} f_n(x) \pi(\{x\}) \geq \inf_n \sum_{x \in S} f_n(x) \pi(\{x\}) \geq \inf_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \sum_{x \in S} f(x) \, \pi(\{x\}),$$
as required.

As we can see above I needed to exclude $f(x) = -\infty$ (otherwise I can't ignore those points), and I used $2^S \subset \mathcal{A}$ to relate the integrals to finite summations. Are these necessary assumptions or can they be removed?

Answer (score -1):

Are singletons measurable? Then your inequality is true. It does not matter that $f$ be finite. You don't use it in your proof.

However you should remove from the definition of $\bar{\mathcal F}$ the functions $f$ such that $\pi(f=+\infty)$ and $\pi(f=-\infty)$ are positive, because then the integral is not well defined.

Comment: I am not assuming singletons are measurable. (Of course, if singletons are measurable and, in my notation, the set $S$ is finite, then certainly any element of $2^S$ must be measurable.) Does that make the result incorrect?

Comment: If singletons are not measurable then there is no such thing as $\pi(\{x\})$ as you wrote in your proof.

Comment: Correct, there is no such thing -- however the question is whether the claim is correct or not... (for example, there could be another proof...)